# OpenGL ES 3: glGenerateMipmap geometric constraints

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-3.0

I'm working on a mobile OpenGL application for android, using OpenGL ES3.x for the graphics.

I would like to use the `glGenerateMipmap` function, yet I feel ill at ease because I remember that, at least with prior versions of OpenGL, there where some geometric constraints on the size of the texture (square, n-pot textures if I remember correctly).

The reference page [glGenerateMipmap for OpenGL ES3](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man3/html/glGenerateMipmap.xhtml) doesn't report anything like that anymore, and a cursory test on a couple of devices seems to confirm the information.

Still, given how recent OpenGL ES3 is (and taking into account the quality of some mobile OpenGL implementation...), I would feel more reassured if someone with first-hand experience would confirm that using it is also ok *in the real world*.

The question boils down to this:

1. Is it true that `glGenerateMipmap` on OpenGL ES 3 doesn't place limits on the geometry of the texture?
2. And if so, is it safe to use it on non square, non n-pot textures in the wild?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those restrictions on non-power of two textures are officially gone in ES 3.0. The corresponding language from the ES 2.0 spec is nowhere to be found in he ES 3.0 spec. In setion E.1, which lists the new features of ES 3.0 compared to ES 2.0, it also explicitly mentions this:

> non-power-of-two textures with full wrap mode support and mipmapping

So yes, you can safely use `glGenerateMipmap()` on NPOT textures. There is one subtle but important restriction:

> If the level_base array was not speciﬁed with an unsized internal format from table3.3 or a sized internal format that is both color-renderable and texture-ﬁlterable according to table 3.13, an INVALID_OPERATION error is generated.

This means that for example `glGenerateMipmap()` is not supported for any integer formats (since they are not texture-filterable), and also not for any float formats (since they are not color-renderable).

I don't think being square was ever really a restriction on textures in OpenGL. It definitely wasn't in ES 2.0, and is not in ES 3.0.

Comment: Thank you for the very clear and very accurate answer (PS: yesterday I was a bit groggy, and I probably made the "square" thing up... :) )